# Removing classes defined by a jQuery attribute selector from the results of a jQuery attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basic problem, I just want to target all classes that end with a specified string on all elements of a class that ends with a specified string, and remove those classes.

This code doesn't work, but it's close to what I want:

```
$('[class$="_active"]').removeClass($('[class$="_active"]'))
```

*$('[class$="_active"]')* returns a jQuery.fn.init object which I can work through with *.each(index,item)*. I thought it would then be as simple as *item.removeClass($('[class$="_active"]'))* but the code below does not work either:

```
$('[class$="_active"]').each(function(index,item){
        item.removeClass($('[class$="_active"]'))
})
```

The removeClass function does not work on the items in my each function. At this point I'm considering stringifying each item, figuring out the text immediately before "_active", removing it from the string along with "_active", then returning the reformed result. But this is just getting too complicated for a basic problem that I assume has a basic answer that I overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute containing selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) and [attribute ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to get all element with a certain class which ends with `_active`. To remove the class first you have to extract the certain class from the class list using [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method(it's only necessary if there are multiple classes for an element).

```
$('[class$="_active"],[class*="_active "]').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('class').match(/\S+_active\b/)[0])
    // or $(this).removeClass(this.className.match(/\S+_active\b/)[0])
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working on all my elements except SVG paths for some reason. "Uncaught TypeError: this.className.match is not a function
    at SVGPathElement." Looking into why right now...

Comment: @JMcFar :  try `$(this).attr('class').match(/\S+_active\b/)[0]`

Comment: Wow. Thanks. don't really understand what I just did, but that worked. I'll have to look into it more, but it works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JMcFar : /\S+_active\b/ is regex for getting the certain class

Comment: @JMcFar : `$(this).attr('class')` for gtting class attribute

Comment: @JMcFar :  `[class*="_active "]`  is added to get element which has the class and it's in between other classes(space separated)

Answer (score 0):

Just one lovely Solution

```
$('[class$="_active"]').each(function(i){$(this).removeClass(this.className)})
```

this is my jsfiddle link, have a look
https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/mgzf2boL/7/

Comment: The problem with this solution, unless I've got it wrong, is it will remove *every* class from the targeted element, not just the classes which end in '_active'